# Solving a Problem with Bearing

Tags: trigonometry

> A plane flies 1.3 hr at 110mph on a bearing of 38 degrees. It then
>   turns and flies 1.5 hr at the same speed on a bearing of 128 degrees.
>   How far is the plane from its starting point?

To solve this, I have drawn a rough sketch. I have also labeled the appropriate sides at 143 miles (distance = rate * time; 1.3hr * 110mph) and 165 miles (1.5hr * 110mph).

But I am having a difficult time concluding which angle within the sketch is the 90 degree angle to allow me to use a trigonometric function or the Pythagorean theorem to solve it.

Edit: It is really important for me to know how to determine the measure of any angle that can be inferred. Not only because I am expecting the professor to attempt to fool us by providing measures where the triangle in question is not a right triangle, but because I thought I had already mastered this skill previously.

Comment: The 90 degree angle is created when the plane changes its bearings, so your two sides are the legs.

Comment: How do we know that the angle when the plane changes its bearings is the right angle? The first angle created is 38, then it changes at 128 degrees.

Comment: @MattR At the risk of stating the obvious $\,128-38=90\,$, and $90^\circ$ *is* a right angle.

Comment: I understand that, but why exactly are we subtracting 38 from 128? Thanks for stating the obvious--it's been years since I've done any math.

Answer (score 1):

Since you turn a total of $90^{\circ}$ the path of the plane forms a right triangle and the two given paths are the legs.

Using pythagorean $a^2+b^2=c^2$, where here $a=1.3\cdot 110=143$ and $b=1.5\cdot 110=165$, so $c=\sqrt{(1.3\cdot 110)^2+(1.5\cdot 110)^2} = 218.344 \text{ mi}$

[image]

Comment: My concern is: How do we know that we have a right triangle? If it's not, we cannot validly apply the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @MattR you travel $143$ miles in one direction. That's a line. Then you turn $90^{\circ}$ and travel $165$ miles. That's two lines that come together at an angle of $90^{\circ}$ and you want to find the distance from the start to end, which is the hypotenuse.

Comment: But how did you get 90 degrees out of 38 and a 128? Another user mentioned that he subtracted 38 from 128, but what allows us to do that? Thank you very much for providing a sketch, by the way.

Comment: @MattR if you're traveling in one direction (your bearing) and you turn a new direction (a new bearing), then the angle of your turn is the difference of the bearings. I didn't label the bearings on my chart, but try drawing your own path of the plane, label the bearings, and see why that's true.